# How to generate/create embedding code for other websites

Tags: javascript, html, embed

We have a web site designed to supply visitors to listen various songs&albums of specific artists and playlists created by editors or users themselves. Main player we use on site is flowplayer.

Additionally, We are working on a function that provides visitors with getting the embed code of a song/album/playlist that is planned to be automatically generated after clicking "Get embed code" button on related song&playlist page. Also, in accordance with our plans, users should have an ability to customize the width, length and theme parameters before getting embed code of what they listen actually. There are several top websites like spotify and apple music doing this function.

I conducted my researches about this topic on many resources for hours. However, what I encountered is mostly about obtaining embed code of a specific video&song and where to place it in the source code of user's own sites. I'm interested on the other side of the process, "kitchen". Therefore, due to that I couldn't find any sufficient source/document, I came here to ask great people who know the drill around this subject to help my question, at least canalize me to correct&detailed resources for our project.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so hard.

Most video embed codes work by adding an `iframe` to the site where the code is inserted. The iframe points on a special page on the service provider's web site, which serves the video.

All you have to do is, to write the code manually first, to see if the whole concept is working.

When your code is ready, you can think about automation and adding parameters to it.

**A quick example:**

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/videoembed/video/h34ghghwktya/?w=480&h=320" width="480" height="320"></iframe>
```

This is all the embed code you need. The rest (showing the video, etc.) will be done on your own server ("http://yoursite.com/videoembed/video/h34ghghwktya/?w=480&h=320").

The source of the `iframe` is on your server, and could receive any parameters.

When you're done with this, you can test it by adding this code to a site. When the video displays and plays, you can work on automating the code.

**Code automation:**

Create a template of the code, which contains all parts that won't be changed (static parts), and add placeholders for the configurable parts (parameters).

*Example:*

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/videoembed/video/{$videoid}/?w={$formwidth}&h={$formheight}" width="{$formwidth}" height="{$formheight}"></iframe>
```

Then create a HTML form which will have controls for all the parameters you would like to set. Make sure, they have some decent defaults.

All the form would do is, to replace the placeholders in the template with your parameters and display the result in a textarea.

The code generator can be written in Javascript and HTML, no server side code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts quite simple in my opinion.

1. Create any css and javascript code in separate files for client to include in their website. They don't need any unnecessary code.
2. Create a html structure - divs and styles. Basically you will provide html code to be incorporated in other websites.
3. Create an editor for embedded code. Something like a facebook like and shere buttons. There you can let the user change the size and color of your songs playlist or whatever you want to give other websites to use.
4. You can also provide a [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098802/how-to-create-embed-code-for-other-sites) to your website so all resources are accessed from within your pages. Again providing parametrization for custom use.

And that is it for the main part. You can optionally track which sites are using your player, how many times they click and so on.

There is no universal way. You can do it how you need it and how you like it.